# Mysql sum two column timestamps

Tags: mysql, time

I have columns Mon, Tue, wed, thu, fri, sat, sun  with timestamps for every day to a project in times table

I need to get total sum of hours spent by adding all columns for a project.

My actual query is like this -

My Actually query is like this - `SELECT time(SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(fri))) + SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(thu))) + SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(tue)))) FROM timesheets WHERE project_id = 5`

Could anyone help me on writing exact query to fetch all the columns time and sum as a total

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there exists a time function that takes more than two arguments to sum them.
Following snippet may be helpful to you:

```
select 
    addtime( mon, addtime( tue, addtime( wed, addtime( thu, 
             addtime( fri, addtime( sat, sun ) ) ) ) ) ) total_time_spent
```

Above query returns total time spent in `hours:minutes:seconds` format.
To select only hours spent in total, use `time_format` function.

```
select time_format( total_time_spent, '%H' ) total_hours_spent
```

Note that this query only returns hours part of the total time spent. You will loose minutes and seconds if any exists.

**Update**:
Following snippet can give you total hours and minutes spent.

```
select 
    time_format( 
        addtime( mon, addtime( tue, addtime( wed, addtime( thu, 
            addtime( fri, addtime( sat, sun ) ) ) ) ) ),
        '%H:%i' ) total_hours_and_mins_spent
```

Comment: yeah.. it is returning 7 rows and how can we get final sum using the same query . thanks

Comment: @Sri Didn't the second snippet help you?

Comment: thanks, but still i need to have total sum of all days (hours:minutes) and can not ommit minutes and sec as this is for generating revenue reports

Comment: thanks a lot, i also tried sum(time_format( 
        addtime( mon .....)) to get total hours but the result is showing wrong as (1.3 + 3.3 should result 5 but resulting 4.6)

Comment: @Sri My answer returns total hours in `'%H:%i'` format for a record. Why are you using `sum` function here? Are you summing data from other records too?

Comment: yes, i need to sum all records for a week for total hours from sql

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried ?

```
SELECT ADDTIME(time1, time2);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very long chapter in [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) about dates and times including parsing, types, conversion and formats.

Cast your columns to `TIME` type and benefit from it:

```
SELECT Mon + Tue
```